# Allow max 4 checked checkboxes under max two parent containers

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox, count, limit

I have a form that holds multiple (>10) subscription containers which each include one or two checkboxes. E.g. subscription 1 (div container) holds two options (checkboxes) which can be checked if other checkboxes under other subscription containers are unchecked or no more than one subscription container has checkbox(es) checked.

```
<div class="subscription1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b"></input>
</div>
<div class="subscription2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="a"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b"></input>
</div>
```

Total limit of checked checkboxes is 4 under maximum of 2 two parent containers. (2x2=4)

It should first check on checkbox change that if parent container's siblings have checked checkboxes. If they have then disable or hide parent container's siblings that don't have checked checkboxes (in other words show only current selection).

And vice versa when changing checkbox status it should reveal parent containers that have unchecked checkboxes if the number of parent's siblings with checked checkboxes is 1 or less.

Jquery selectors(at first sight) could be something like:

```
$allotherparents = $(this).parent('.parent').siblings()

$notchecked = $allotherparents.filter('input:not(:checked)')

$checked = $allotherparents.filter('input:checked')
```

Then in short count the lengths, evaluate and do changes. However, I'm not convinced with these selectors since only first one returns length > 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ug3crxcy/

```
$allotherparents = $(this).parent('.parent').siblings('.parent');

$notchecked = $allotherparents.filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input:checked').length === 0;
});

$checked = $allotherparents.filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('input:checked').length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Closer. Now it works quite well but when unchecking an item it won't reverse the "limit effect"(fadeto,disabled) until all checkboxes are unchecked. I',m debugging these forementioned figures and when unchecking from another subscription parent it won't have any affect on the number of unchecked subscriptions (parents). Other way it seems to work e.g. checking +1 but unchecking won't -1.